# 'SESSION_CONTEXT' is not a recognized built-in function name - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, row-level-security

I have an Azure SQL Database. I am trying to execute the following query on SQL Server Management Studio 2016:

```
ALTER TABLE Contacts ADD UserId nvarchar(128)
    DEFAULT CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserId') AS nvarchar(128))
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 22
'SESSION_CONTEXT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

I am following this row level security tutorial: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security.md

Comment: Try dbo.SESSION_CONTEXT

Comment: What is `@@version`?

Comment: @Danieboy dbo.SESSION_CONTEXT does not work

Comment: @MartinSmith What do you mean?

Comment: What is the result of executing `select @@version`?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 11.0.9231.377 Aug 15 2016 17:25:18 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Works fine for me in `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Aug 23 2016 14:21:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation `

Comment: Problem solved! I upgraded my Azure SQL Server and now it works @MartinSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upgrade your SQL Server on Azure portal to V12. I think this could work.